# Nextjs loading bar while logging in not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to generate a progress bar when the user logs to improve the user experience but I can't understand why the progress bar component isn't being rendered.

I'm using react-hook-form and isLoading state and then rendering the loading bar or the form conditionally from that:

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting, isSubmitSuccessful },
    reset,
  } = useForm<FormSchemaType>({ resolver: zodResolver(formSchema) });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormSchemaType> = (data) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      signIn("credentials", {
        ...data,
        redirect: false,
      }).then((callback) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (callback?.ok) {
          toast.success("Logged in!");
          router.refresh();
        }

        if (callback?.error) {
          toast.error(callback.error);
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
  };
  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogTrigger className="w-full">
        <Subcategory
          label="Login"
          icon={FaUserCheck}
          // className={`${disabled && "bg-gray-700 cursor-not-allowed"}`}
          // inverted={disabled ? true : false}
        />
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle className="mb-2 text-center">Login</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            {isLoading ? (
              <Progress value={60} className="w-full" />
            ) : (
              <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                className="flex flex-col gap-4"
              >
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  id="email"
                  {...register("email")}
                  placeholder="Email"
                />
                {errors.email && (
                  <ErrorMessage message={errors.email?.message} />
                )}

                <Input
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  {...register("password")}
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
                {errors.password && (
                  <ErrorMessage message={errors.password?.message} />
                )}
                <Button type="submit" className="bg-lightbackground w-full">
                  <DialogClose />
                  Login
                </Button>
              </form>
            )}
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

I added in a timeout to mimic some delay but while loading in, the modal just shows nothing, neither the progress or the form. My initial thought is that the button is rerendering the component which is setting isLoading to false, but then atleast form would be showing. Neither components are showing after button press.

Not sure why